# Python in vscode not executing

Tags: python

I am trying to run python on vs code, however I keep getting the message in the terminal as

```
***[Running] python -u "c:\Users\User\Documents\Learning\Programming\Python\Vs code use\conditions.py"
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.114 seconds
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\User\Documents\Learning\Programming\Python\Vs code use\conditions.py"
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.161 seconds
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\User\Documents\Learning\Programming\Python\Vs code use\conditions.py"
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.126 seconds
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\User\Documents\Learning\Programming\Python\Vs code use\conditions.py"
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.133 seconds
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\User\Documents\Learning\Programming\Python\Vs code use\conditions.py"
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.144 seconds
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\User\Documents\Learning\Programming\Python\Vs code use\conditions.py"
Hello
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.123 seconds***
```

I have python installed and have downloaded python extension from microsoft.
What could be the issue please?

Comment: It looks like your code is indeed running. If your code doesn’t produce any output, then you wont see anything when the code has finished running. Please provide a sample of your code that you expect to produce a visible output

Comment: It's running fine! You maybe just don't have any output in your code.